# Show parent DIV if children spans have class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out why this is not working. I have a `div` that I'd like to be toggled open if it has one or more `span` children with a class of `.reqiredError`.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwL8q3v0/)

```
<div class="more-content" style="display:none;">
    <div class="col-xs-5 form-group">
        <label for="dua-status">
            Status: 
            <span class="required">*</span> 
            <span class="requiredError">Required Field</span>
        </label>
        <select id="dua-status">
            <option>Open</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('span').hasClass('requiredError')) {
        $(this).closest().parent('div.more-content').fadeIn(0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the target element then use .closest() find the the target ancestor element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.requiredError').closest('.more-content').fadeIn(0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more-content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="col-xs-5 form-group">
    <label for="dua-status">Status: <span class="required">*</span>  <span class="requiredError">Required Field</span>
    </label>
    <select id="dua-status">
      <option>Open</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[closest vs has](http://jsperf.com/closest-vs-has)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `if` statement.

Rather, target them with a selector using [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/). The advantage of this is you do not have to navigate up to parent as the context will be the parent div that **has** those spans

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div.more-content:has(.requiredError)').fadeIn(0);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="more-content" style="display:none;">
  <div class="col-xs-5 form-group">
    <label for="dua-status">Status: <span class="required">*</span>  <span class="requiredError">Required Field</span>
    </label>
    <select id="dua-status">
      <option>Open</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```